# GULP displaying "ACCESS DENIED"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm new to the incredible world of Gulp. I've created a gulpfile which successfully reads/writes/compiles sass/css/js/html etc. But when I come to view the site on `localhost:1337` all I get is "ACCESS DENIED" & "File not found" when loading `localhost:1337/index.html`

Below is the gulp file (minus dependencies...)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Update: I believe I'm missing some config option of sorts for ecstatic to allow the file to load when I navigate to localhost:1337/index.html as localhost:1337/app/index.html & localhost:1337/dist/index.html are loading fine in the browser.

```
// options
var config = {
    html_src:           "app/**/*.html",
    sass_src:           "app/assets/styles/main.scss",
    js_src:             "app/assets/scripts/**/*.js",
    css_dest:           "dist/assets/styles",
    js_dest:            "dist/assets/styles",
    js_concat_target:   "main.js",
    http_port:          "1337",
    livereload_port:    "35729"
};

// end config || begin tasks

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src(config.sass_src)
        .pipe(sass({style:"expanded" }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer("last 2 version", "safari 5", "ie 8", "ie 9", "opera 12.1", "ios 6", "android 4"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css_dest))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css_dest))
        .pipe(livereload(server))
        //.pipe(notify({ message:"styles task complete" }));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src(config.js_src)
        .pipe(jshint(/* ".jshintrc" */))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(concat(config.js_concat_target))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js_dest))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js_dest))
        .pipe(livereload())
        //.pipe(notify({ message: "scripts task complete" }));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src(config.html_src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
        .pipe(livereload())
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    gulp.src([config.css_dest, config.js_dest], { read: false })
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    server.listen(config.livereload_port);
    http.createServer(ecstatic({ root: __dirname} )).listen(config.http_port);
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.yellow('HTTP Server running on port ' + config.http_port));
    gulp.watch(config.sass_src, ['styles'])._watcher.on('all', livereload);
    gulp.watch(config.js_src, ['scripts'])._watcher.on('all', livereload);
    gulp.watch(config.html_src, ['html'])._watcher.on('all', livereload);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your server's root is set to the wrong directory. At the moment it's set to `__dirname` which would be the directory that your gulpfile is in, but your files are being outputted to the `dist` subdirectory.

Either try changing

```
http.createServer(ecstatic({root: __dirname})).listen(config.http_port);
```

to

```
http.createServer(ecstatic({root: 'dist'})).listen(config.http_port);
```

or access your `index.html` file at `localhost:1337/dist/index.html`